# Angular Laravel Authentication

Tags: angular, laravel, cors

I have a problem with my angular application. As it is get api call from laravel backend. I am hosting both of them on the same domain but with different subdomains.Angular project at (beta.easyschools.org) $ backend at (erp.easyschools.org) when I try to log in within the app I keep getting this error message [No access origin headers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFSEJ.png). however when I put the dist folder of the angular app in my public folder of the laravel I can access the application and log in successful. but I have another problem that any api that I try to call I receive message "unauthenticated". can't find any solution on the internet for this problem.

Important note: Everything works fine in local environment but when I try it on my apache server it is not working as metiond above. although I have configured my backend .htaccess and apache2 server to accept headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest installing [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) If you have not already and this will candle your Cross-Origin Access

So just install it with

`$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors`

Add

`\Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class`

To your API middlewares and standard Routes too

Comment: I have installed it already that's why i am telling you it's working on local enviroment

Comment: I have never had to do anything different when i pushed my site live

Comment: it's really weird i don't understand the problem and it made me frustrated.

Comment: yes same problem unauthenticated. that's only with the server but if local host it works

Comment: I will have a speak to my coworker about how he got his working on Azure

Comment: I solved it. I had to put the Headers rules in the httpd.conf of the Apache2. now I am with anouther error 403